# php cookies and session variables form

Tags: php, forms, session, variables, cookies

I am trying to create a simple form / page that uses some basic cookie and session stuff to produce some user-specific data. I was moving along good until I came across a few problems that I can’t figure out. On my first page everything is good except for I just want the NAME of the browser the user is using. (for example, I want just the simple title: Firefox instead of the whole long version of the browser.) I’ve seen this be done so I think it’s possible, I just don’t know how to do it!

My real problems come up right about here, because I’m not exactly sure how to store the IP address, browser info and the current date/time (which I want shown on page 2) as session variables. Tried a few things I found, but I don’t think I was doing it right.

I also worked endlessly on trying to store the username and passwords as two separate cookies each...suggestions? Finally, what do I need to do to have a location header (used to call form_data.php) with output buffering? I feel like I was following cookies/sessions until I actually tried to use them!

As you can tell, I’m new to PHP (but not programming in general) so while I have an understanding of some of this, I’m trying to learn (and master) the unique qualities of PHP! I’ll be so grateful for any help you can offer!

Code time! (Not sure this will be that helpful, considering I probably did everything wrong! LOL) This is a totally stripped-down version of my code. Tried to post my cleanest version, even though it doesn’t have much info, so that you could easily see what i was trying to do.

main file code:

```
<?php
header('Location: form_data.php');


 setcookie('username', $_POST['username']);
 setcookie('password', $_POST['password']);
 //I know this isn't working.
 //honestly I just left this in here as to show where I had been
 //trying to save the cookie data. Pretty obvious how bad my
 //trial and error with this went!

 }
 ?>


 <?php

 $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 echo " By the way, your IP address is: </b>".$_SESSION['ip']."<br />";
 echo " You already know this, but the browser you are currently using
 to view this page is:<br/>";  //What is the correct function that I should be using here?
 echo "<form action=\"form_data.php\" method=\"post\">";
 echo "username:<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"20\" value=\"\"><br/>";
 echo "password:<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" size=\"20\" value=\"\"><br/>";
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit, please\" />";
 echo "<br /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submitted\" value=\"true\" />";
 ?>
```

form_data.php:

```
    <?php

echo "Hello, ".$username;//I'm trying to get the cookie data for the username
echo "Your password is ".$password; //Samething here (want cookie data)
echo "The date and time you entered this form is: ".date("F j, Y")." -- ".date("g:i a");
echo "<br/>Your IP:".$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "<br/>Your broswer:".;//I want full browser data here... don't know how to do it.
//Overall, was this the way to get the session variables for IP, date/time and browser?
echo  "Thank you for filling out this form!";
?>
```

Comment: You definitely won't be writing any session data whatsoever like this without calling `session_start();` the first thing at the top of your code.

Comment: ah, yes. Didn't even realize that...see I've only ever seen other examples of what i'm trying to do...never written anything like this myself so I was at a bit of a loss trying to figure out what went where, etc. Any more suggestions/examples?

Comment: have you read http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php ?

Comment: There is **NEVER** any good reason to store the password in a cookie. And storing the username in a cookie is nearly as bad

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment elsewhere you should NEVER store passwords and usernames in cookies.

> I just want the NAME of the browser

See the [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) fn

> not exactly sure how to store the IP address, ....but I don’t think I was doing it right

If you told us what you were expecting to see and what you actually saw then it would be a help.

You are not calling session_start() in your code.

> header('Location: form_data.php');
>   ...
>   ?>

Unless you explicitly tell the PHP code to ignore user abort, the remainder of the code on this page will probably not execute.

Why are you trying to store the IP address in the session anyway?

> Finally, what do I need to do to have a location header (used to call form_data.php) with output buffering?

While it is technically possible to include content with a redirect header, usually browsers will just ignore it. If you want the content to show on screen before the user os sent to the next page, then return a 200 response and do the redirect via javascript or a meta refresh directive.

Comment: I know its never good to store a password as cookie...which is why i don't know how to do it! But for exercise purposes I needed to create a little form with all the information I outlined in my original post. The reason im here is because all of the requirements seem a little unwise and I was really strugling with trying to find any good information on them! Any more suggestions or examples are welcomed by anyone please...I'm still struggling with creating a working page! (And I tried to post this as a comment, but i wasn't able to!)